# EPIServer 6 doesnt let admin delete page

Tags: admin, episerver, episerver-6-r2

I have an issue where EPIServer 6 says "insufficient privileges to change this page". I am 100% sure that I'm the highest admin available, and I have tried on my colleagues admin accounts aswell.

This is the icon showing:

[image]

The page was previously forcefully deleted from the project giving a and error when trying to access it from the menu. I added the page back in the project, but still cannot delete it via episerver on the page..

Any ideas? Google search turns up dry..

Comment: Being admin or having the highest access right doesn't make all the pages readable by default.  Have you checked which groups your current user belongs to and which groups/users have read access to the page? Try running the code Role.GetRolesForUser and see which roles .Net think you belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the EPiServer database directly you can run this script in order to force delete a page. At least if you're using EPiServer 6.

```
--- Force EPiServer page deletion
declare @pageIDtoDelete int
set @pageIDtoDelete = <INSERT PAGE ID HERE>

delete from tblWorkProperty where fkWorkPageID in (select pkID from tblWorkPage where fkPageID = @pageIDtoDelete)
delete from tblWorkPage where fkPageID = @pageIDtoDelete
delete from tblProperty where fkPageId = @pageIDtoDelete
delete from tblAccess where fkPageID = @pageIDtoDelete
delete from tblPageLanguage where fkPageID = @pageIDtoDelete
delete from tblPage where pkID = @pageIDtoDelete
```

Answer (score 3):

Switch over to Admin mode, and check what groups your user is part of. Then go to Set Access Rights (still in Admin mode), select the page in the tree, and make sure that any of the groups your user is part of has Delete or Administer rights for the page. If none do, check if your user has any of those rights for the page. If not, then add those rights for your user, switch to Edit mode and delete the page.

If it still doesn't work, make the same checks for the Recycle Bin.

Comment: I check all that :/ It's all in order, something fishy seems to be going on

Comment: Did you also check the parent page of the page you are trying to delete?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to delete it through code using the DataFactory Delete method with a RequiredAccess of None.

Although, that won't clarify *why* you can't delete the page through the UI... :/

Comment: True, something weird must have happened making it not possible to delete the page :/